# RuntimeError: CUDA error: CUBLAS_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED when calling `cublasCreate(handle)` ```

Tags: java, python, pytorch

I'm trying to convert code from java to python. For that I'm using [Facebook's Transcoder](https://github.com/facebookresearch/TransCoder) and while running the following command on my [google colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1NwFxQaK96-M1mwDvmiNH1tKd9Z_qRf5Y#scrollTo=nsLQJ03oCuBu), I'm getting the following error (I guess all the dependencies have been installed):

**Command**

```
!python TransCoder/translate.py --src_lang java --tgt_lang python \\
--BPE_path TransCoder/data/BPE_with_comments_codes --model_path model_1.pth < a.java
```

**Error**

```
Loading codes from /content/TransCoder/data/BPE_with_comments_codes ...
Read 50000 codes from the codes file.
/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:662: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [59,0,0], thread: [64,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:662: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [59,0,0], thread: [65,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:662: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [59,0,0], thread: [66,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
.
.
.
/pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Indexing.cu:662: indexSelectLargeIndex: block: [59,0,0], thread: [127,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TransCoder/translate.py", line 179, in <module>
    input, lang1=params.src_lang, lang2=params.tgt_lang, beam_size=params.beam_size)
  File "TransCoder/translate.py", line 129, in translate
    langs=langs1, causal=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/content/TransCoder/XLM/src/model/transformer.py", line 328, in forward
    return self.fwd(**kwargs)
  File "/content/TransCoder/XLM/src/model/transformer.py", line 400, in fwd
    attn = self.attentions[i](tensor, attn_mask, use_cache=use_cache)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/content/TransCoder/XLM/src/model/transformer.py", line 182, in forward
    q = shape(self.q_lin(input))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 889, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py", line 94, in forward
    return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 1753, in linear
    return torch._C._nn.linear(input, weight, bias)
RuntimeError: CUDA error: CUBLAS_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED when calling `cublasCreate(handle)`
```

Comment: If you're trying to use PyTorch from Java, instead of going through its Python API, it's probably going to be more reliable to use its C++ API directly with something like the JavaCPP Presets for PyTorch: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/pytorch

Comment: Actually, I've no idea of all these. I was trying to get my code converted.